# access docker container in kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I have a docker container with an application exposing port 8080.
I can run it and access it on my local computer:

```
$ docker run -p 33333:8080 foo
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I can test it with:

```
$ nc -v locahost 33333
connection succeeded!
```

However when I deploy it in Kubernetes it doesn't work.
Here is the manifest file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo-pod
  namespace: foo
  labels:
    name: foo-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: foo
    image: bar/foo:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo-service
  namespace: foo
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
    - NodePort: 33333
  selector:
    name: foo-pod
```

Deployed with:

```
$ kubectl apply -f foo.yaml 
$ nc -v <publicIP> 33333
Connection refused
```

I don't understand why I cannot access it...

Comment: I noted that running a container only with nc will work:

Answer (score 1):

The problem  was that the application was listening on IP `127.0.0.1`.
It needs to listen on `0.0.0.0` to work in kubernetes. A change in the application code did the trick.